# driver.quit in selenium 3.0.2 firefox 50.1.0 firefox has stopped working

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

[image]

i am using selenium 3 to interact with Firefox 50.1.0

while i am running `driver.quit()` Firefox gives error while closing the browser

`driver.close()` is not working at all

is this a version issue ? if yes which version should i install in Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you include the code, so we can test it? see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: code is too big, not sure if that will help

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code example. Can you also include the error that is occurring?

Comment: Tested on 10.11.6 macosx, selenium 3.0.2, and firefox 50.1.0, and it works here.

Comment: i am using windows 7, that might be the issue

Comment: Can you include any of the crash report details as part of your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47)

Comment: look at this question [firefox-via-geckodriver-throws-exception-on-quit-in-selenium-3-0-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113331/firefox-via-geckodriver-throws-exception-on-quit-in-selenium-3-0-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to downgrade firefox:

- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0b9/win64/en-US/
- https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/49.0b9/win32/en-US/

Try using a different driver, chrome, edge, IE, opera.

Basically, try downgrading selenium along with the drivers until you find a version that works possibly `selenium==2.53.6` and `firefox==46.x`

Once you find a version that works, be extra sure to save a profile that has autoupdate turned off, and then use it, or just turn it off everytime:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('app.update.auto', False)
profile.set_preference('app.update.enabled', False)
profile.set_preference('app.update.silent', False)
downgraded_firefox = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe'
binary = webdriver.FirefoxBinary(downgraded_firefox)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, firefox_binary=binary)
```

See example of profiles:

- [Setting selenium to use custom profile, but it keeps opening with default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954682/setting-selenium-to-use-custom-profile-but-it-keeps-opening-with-default)
- [Stopping auto update of Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182464/stopping-auto-update-of-mozilla-firefox)

If you click on `View problem details` of the popup, you might find similar information on why firefox crashed. See:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027222
- https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7506
- https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3314

Related:

- [Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693106/selenium-2-53-not-working-on-firefox-47?rq=1)

Comment: alright downgrading firefox is not a solution i tried with two versions 48 and 49, finally i was able to do it with chrome

Comment: possibly `selenium==2.53.6` and `firefox==46.x` but chrome works :)

Comment: thanks alot for your time and all the suggestions, yes finally it worked with chrome cheers

Comment: chromedriver = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe'
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://my.maerskline.com/webuser/login')

Answer (score 0):

This is error happens at windows server 2012 and windows 8. It is already reported 
[here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/375). Downgrading to firefox 48.0.2 should fix it

Comment: yup couple of people reported this as bug but there is no input from Mozilla team

Comment: @GAURAVCHHABRA i am testing with firefox 48 until they fix it

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Selenium 3.5 and firefox 54, when setting my own FirefoxProfile instance, for example:

```
var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions() { Profile = new FirefoxProfile() };
```

This looks like a bug in Gecko / Firefox / Selenium, the workaround was setting "browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = false" in the firefox profile preferences.
For example:

```
var firefoxService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);

var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions() { Profile = firefoxProfile };

using (var webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, firefoxOptions, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
{
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

(Saw this at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2701)